# How can I make my tiles fall smoothly?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I'm working on a Tile-Based game and I can't figure out how to make my tiles fall down smoothly like in candy crush. All column tiles fall-down at the same time. And spawn new like how many tile place if null.

What I want:

[image: ExampleSameColumnDown]

## Update [25.12.2015]

But the my code works like this:

[image: MyCode]

## Update [26.12.2015]

Hello Again,

World Scale (x,y)
World Scale OLD: (10,10)
World Scale NEW: (10,11)

Y=11 Tiles type = Empty

Now, when i click the random place like (5,7),above all blocks down to :
block.transform.pozition += new Vector3(0,-1,0);
It's working. But again, when i click same place (5,7) not working...

I changed Y scale 10 to 11. Because, when i clicked tile, the tile will return to Y=11 position and fall down, how many tile place null.

When Tiles state "fallling down", the space between two blocks distance not more "0.01".

I do not know how to do. But I approached. I need to more improve this.

Thanks...

Pseudo-code:

```
When I click the (4,7) coord, the tiles,
tile(4,8) is smooth down the coord(4,7)
tile(4,9) is smooth down the coord(4,8)
tile(4,9) is generate new tile.
```

What I have (Code not working properly :( ):

```
World.Height = 10
World.Widht = 10
Tile X and Y {get, protected set}


public void ColumnDown(int x , int yStart)
{
    if (IsColumnFull(x)) return;

    for (int y = yStart; y < World.Height; y++)
    {
        //Yeni tile spawnla
        if (y + 1 >= World.Height) continue;

        Tile tile = World.GetTileAt(x, y);
        Tile tile2 = World.GetTileAt(x, y + 1);

        GameObject go_Tile = GameObject.Find("Tile-(" + x + "," + y + ")");
        GameObject go_Tile2 = GameObject.Find("Tile-(" + x + "," + (y + 1) + ")");

        if (tile != null)
        {
            if (go_Tile == null && go_Tile2 == null)
            {
                Debug.Log("go_Tile NULL");
                continue;
            }

            tile2 = tile;
            go_Tile2.transform.position += new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
            go_Tile.name = "Tile-(" + x + "," + (y + 1) + ")";
            go_Tile2.name = "Tile-(" + x + "," + (y) + ")";           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: set the translate animation

Comment: translate animation is useless. I dont use unity's gravity, collider, animation etc. only world coordinates, gameobject and camera.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of treating the entire column as one entity, have each candy check if it can fall down.

Each candy checks if it collides with a candy below it (or the floor). If not the candy falls down -using gravity so they fall nice and realistic. Since the candy can only fall down per column, collisions are easy to check.
Do a count for each vertical and have a new candy spawn on top if the number of candy is lower than the total candy a column can contain.

Keep track if any candy has fallen during the update loop. If no candy has fallen the board is 'locked' and a grid is created from the current candy to do your 'match 3' logic.

The beauty of each candy being a separate entity is that you can do collision detection that is beyond the grid. If you ever played the Disney Frozen match-3 game, you'll notice that a horizontal beam can also hit objects that are falling. So you only need to perform the match-3 logic when the board is in a 'locked' state.

Advanced logic can be created to have certain parts of the board to be locked so gameplay can be more fluid (the player can swap tiles while other area's of the board are still falling).

Comment: I'm not using unity's gravity, collions etc... Only using local positions. The FallDown bool is a good idea. My English is not very good.I do not very well understand what you're saying. Can you help me with sample codes or algortihms ?

Thanks...

Comment: You don't have to use unity physics to simulate gravity. Gravity is a simple formula that makes the y velocity faster each loop. If you want to simulate candy falling down smooth you'll have to model each candy individually.

Comment: Have you sample source or algorithm for this? Or can you fix  a bit my code? (:

Comment: For gravity do something like this: `g=9.8f` (some constant that works for your game). Each update: `acceleration+=g*timestep; candy.Y+=acceleration*timestep;`

Comment: Thanks, and  for my other question, my code not working properly have some issuies o dont know how to fix it...

Comment: You need to rethink your code entirely. You are trying to update tiles in a grid which will not give you the smooth result you're looking for. Instead of fixing that better put your effort in changing your approach.

Comment: I need do a colon is completely down. For Example, When mouse clicked on (4,6) destroy the tile, and fall down all tiles how many tiles have above.
I updated my topic, how the code works. Need to fix it. Thank you again. (:

Comment: The problem could not be resolved. :( When i click (4,6) => (4,7),(4,8),(4,9) will be fall down and (4,6) is will be spawn again (4,9) bla bla...

Answer (score -1):

The solution is simple: just use the built-in Physic Engine.

Here's how:

- Instead of using "Box Collider 2D", use "Circle Collider 2D", this
  will solve the block-stuck problem.
- You just need the fall physic, so lock X and Z in RigidBody2D's
  Constraints. Don't worry, you can still control X via your script.

[image]